# Get HTML Form ID within PHP

Tags: php, html

I would like to get the form ID with PHP.
This is my HTML code. Each answer per question, has an ID.

```
<br><br><h3>Vraag 1: Wat is de juiste formule van Arbeid?</h3>

    <input type="radio" name="question-1" id="question-1-A" value="2" />
    <label for="question-1-A">A) Kracht (in Newton) keer Lengte (in meter) </label>

    <input type="radio" name="question-1" id="question-1-B" value="0" />
    <label for="question-1-B">B) Kracht keer Massa</label>

    <input type="radio" name="question-1" id="question-1-C" value="0" />
    <label for="question-1-C">C) Kracht keer valversnelling</label>

    <input type="radio" name="question-1" id="question-1-D" value="0" />
    <label for="question-1-D">D) Geen van deze antwoorden</label>
```

So in PHP, I receive the values like this, to calculate the score:

```
$q1=$_POST['question-1'];
```

But how can I receive the ID and make it so that

```
if (*QUESTION-1-A* *IS FILLED IN*)
{
     echo "You filled in A"
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You can pass `id` in `value` attribute

Comment: Since `id` is available only on client-side, PHP is not going to work. The best way to manipulate with `id` in this way is using JavaScript and not PHP.

Comment: You can use jquery to get the id then send it to php via ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can only access the values passed using POST/GET so you can't access the input IDs or form IDs.
You can however create a hidden element like:

```
<br><br><h3>Vraag 1: Wat is de juiste formule van Arbeid?</h3>

    <input type="radio" name="question-1[]" id="question-1-A" value="2" />
    <label for="question-1-A">A) Kracht (in Newton) keer Lengte (in meter) 
    </label>

    <input type="radio" name="question-1[]" id="question-1-B" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="question-1_ID[]" value="question-1-B"  />
    <label for="question-1-B">B) Kracht keer Massa</label>

    <input type="radio" name="question-1[]" id="question-1-C" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="question-1_ID[]" value="question-1-C"/>
    <label for="question-1-C">C) Kracht keer valversnelling</label>

    <input type="radio" name="question-1[]" id="question-1-D" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="question-1_ID[]" value="question-1-D" />
    <label for="question-1-D">D) Geen van deze antwoorden</label>
```

Now when you post the form you can do:

```
$questions = ["A","B","C","D"];    
foreach($_POST['question-1'] as $index => $response){
    if($response!==''){
        // then there is something in it.
        echo "You filled in Question ".$questions [$index];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will give the same result no matter what answer was selected.

Comment: Those changes don't help. Only the checked radio button will be successful, so the only index in the submitted data will be `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The `id` is only available client side.

The `value` is designed for what you are trying to do. Use the `value` instead.

You'll need to give different answers different `value`s. Your current `value`s do not make sense.

Comment: Maybe his values in this case are meant to accomplish a different purpose :).

Comment: @d3r1ck — Then that purpose should be achieved with something more appropriate (which I'd speculate is the `checked` attribute).

Comment: Well it just works like this. Im calculating the score by adding the values of the question together. I can also make it so that value=1A and in PHP 1A = 2, but why do I get a downvote?

Comment: Move the scoring logic to the server instead. Look up the scope each answer is worth there. Limit the data on the client to actually say what answer the user is giving. (If you put the scores in the HTML then people can view the source to find the correct answers!)